# How to create filter for WP categories?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, categories

I have blog page template, where are displayed posts from category "uncategorized". Is there some easy way, how to add some simple filter buttons for other categories?

It should work as here: w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp
But instead "< div class="filterDiv cars" >BMW< /div >" I need display posts from some category.

This is current code what display posts from all categories on blog page:

```
<section class="blog-page-content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="post-list-wrapper">
```

```html
 <?php 


                    $args = array(
                        // 'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'post_type'  => 'post',
                        'category_name' => 'uncategorized',
                        'orderby'  => 'date',
                        'order'    => 'DESC'
                    );
                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    
                ?>

                <?php

                if (isset($query->posts) && !empty($query->posts) ) {
                    foreach($query->posts as $key => $value) {
                        // var_dump(get_permalink($value));
                        if ($key == 0) {
                            ?>
                            
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="date"> <?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($value->post_date)); ?> </div>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($value) ?>"><h2><?php echo $value->post_title ?></h2> </a>
                                    <p><?php echo custom_excerpt($value->post_content) ?></p>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        else {
                            ?>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="date"> <?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($value->post_date)); ?> </div>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($value) ?>"><h3><?php echo $value->post_title ?></h3> </a>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }

                ?>
```